# This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts a number or a string, and, if the type is string returns 'string' or if the type is number it returns number.

Code:

```
function stringOr1(v: number): number;
function stringOr1(v: string): string;

function stringOr1(v: number | string) {
  if (typeof v == 'string') {
    return 'string';
  }
  else {
    return 1;
  }
}

const s1 = stringOr1('1');
const s2 = stringOr1(1);
```

TS error:

```
This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't let the type inference do the typing for the returned type as it returns `"string" | 1`.

```
function stringOr1(v: number | string): number | string {
  if (typeof v == 'string') {
    return 'string';
  }
  else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

The reason behind why the compiler is doing this is simple, you are not using any variables, so the compiler infers that the return type cannot be wider than `"string" | 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a sample code to use method overloading with interface & class find the sample below & try it out in typescript playground.

```
interface iStrOrI {
 stringOr1(v: number): number;
 stringOr1(v: string): string;
}

class StrOrI implements iStrOrI {
    stringOr1(v: number): number;
    stringOr1(v: string): string;
    stringOr1(v: number | string): string | number {
        if (typeof v == 'string') {
            return 'string';
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Run this code in typescript playground here: [Playground url](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAmAZTFA8lAksgbwChlTkBnTUAcxwEYAKANwC5kQBXAWwCNoBKNp17QA3CTKUoNeszZSagilRDVxAXyJEEAGzjlyyDNjyouABx0QuEcIfSYc%20YmWXTVs1u258oS4b7irgoeUIxeIdRKkUGSKrRhct4iUMgAPm6K8vHpyb6EEq6kwDDIDGAAnuYQAPalTMgAvI3IAOSRrfwFRT3IUBBgHFAgbR2xPZq9yBA65CguU2T9g8PIdONFk2Samlq6%20obGTgBMZpbWtmD2R6YLpJGeQj4CTykbD4kR8dHx4oXIAHoAcg4CAamAABbQZAAdzgFWQdWQNig1BoqBA5g4YGQlWqhh42PY4L6EAQNS4NhAABMINTkDwEVwapQADQgnRwiqGSjw6YAD0swAQYAAdP8PuE2BwQABrMEwkA-dzUXIBaF3IolMp42r1JotdrxTrdRakZZDEZGlWtDauLY9GZzU1mi2rdb-e3-HZaJhwVJSJxNdgQGFGRx4Bj8P7kkDkGpWUU6GrUBiBvCiyUMABEdGz-Gj2hqcYTECTKbTEdwmfisjoBb%20foDVeDIFD4ZMuGOUZjxfjieTqfT1az2eO%20cLsf7ZcHlc7NZVsmODaAA)

when you are doing a method overloading, specifying explicit return types during implementation will not give you that error during transpile phase.

Useful information on method/function overloading https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads